# Finding an asymptotically tight bound for a recurrence using the substitution method

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, recurrence-relations

I need to find an asymptotically tight bound for $T(n) = T\left(\sqrt{n}\right) +  \theta\left(\log\log n\right)$,

$T(4) = 1$.

I think the first step is to define $m =\log\log n$. What do I do now?

Thanks.